# MySql cannot connect error -- it only happens sometimes

Tags: mysql, database

I get the following exception in my project (.NET socket server):

`ERROR HY000: [ODBC Driver 3.51] Can't connect to MySQL server 'someHost' (10060)`

The error does not occur every single time, though.  So that rules out configuration errors or incorrect login details.  Also when I show all my %max% variables, I'm not getting close on any of them.  Unfortunately the verbosity of the logging cannot be changed, and the logs have not been written to recently.

What can cause these sporadic connect failures?

Comment: Poor network connectivity between the client and host?  Hitting max # of connections?

Comment: Possibly the former, which I'm running packet captures to check.  The latter is not the case -- I've checked my project's activity in processlist and looked at all my %max% values and I'm getting nowhere close.